# Get the Index of an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have the following code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, LLLL d", Locale.US);
String[] suspendedDates = {
        "Tuesday, January 1",
        "Monday, January 21",
        "Sunday, February 10",
        "Tuesday, February 12",
        "Wednesday, February 13",
        "Monday, February 18",
        "Sunday, February 24",
        "Tuesday, March 26",
        "Wednesday, March 27",
        "Thursday, March 28",
        "Friday, March 29",
        "Monday, April 1",
        "Tuesday, April 2",
        "Thursday, May 2",
        "Friday, May 3",
        "Thursday, May 9",
        "Wednesday, May 15",
        "Thursday, May 16",
        "Monday, May 27",
        "Thursday, July 4",
        "Wednesday, August 7",
        "Thursday, August 8",
        "Friday, August 9",
        "Thursday, August 15",
        "Monday, September 2",
        "Thursday, September 5",
        "Friday, September 6",
        "Saturday, September 14",
        "Thursday, September 19",
        "Friday, September 20",
        "Thursday, September 26",
        "Friday, September 27",
        "Monday, October 14",
        "Tuesday, October 15",
        "Wednesday, October 16",
        "Thursday, October 17",
        "Friday, November 1",
        "Sunday, November 3",
        "Tuesday, November 5",
        "Monday, November 11",
        "Thursday, November 28",
        "Sunday, December 8",
        "Wednesday, December 25"
};
```

And the following line compares and returns true if it matches:

```
Arrays.asList(suspendedDates).contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))
```

What I want to know is, How to check at what Index does it match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` method in the `List` interface for this. And since `Arrays.asList(suspendedDates)` gives you a `List` you can use this code:

```
int index = Arrays.asList(suspendedDates).indexOf(...)
```

This will return `-1` if it was not found.

And as a side note, please consider using the `Date` class instead of storing your dates in Strings.

Comment: I was able to get it work. Thank you!